# APACHE/NGINX fine tuning for Apache Benchmark testing

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, stress-testing, ab

I need to know some tuning configuration about APACHE/NGINX. I use Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS on VirtuaBox with two VM: one with APACHE 2.2.22, the other with NGINX 1.1.19. In addition I installed PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5.35. I need to make some testing on a local website using AB Bench. In particulare I'd like to make 100000 connections with concurrency from 100 up to 1000, with Connection KeepAlive option disabled. The only things I was able to make was to disable KeepAlive and increase the number of connection in NGINX. But I found difficulties in increasing the number of concurrency more than 100.

In apache2.conf I only disabled KeepAlive. Having tested like this:

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://www.mysite.com/
```

the error was:

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

In nginx.conf I only set:

```
worker_connections 100000;
keepalive_timeout 0;
```

The test was completed with a high number of "Failed requests" and of "Non-2xx resposes".
In both cases I think I found good results with a concurrency of 100. How can I tuning better both web servers? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Turn keepalive back on?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. With KeepAlive enabled the music remains the same. So I think it is a matter of fine tuning. But I don't really know to go further.